# true or false (p<0.05)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

Can someone with more experience explain this statement to me?

> If one, with a hypothesis test, tests for equal means in two samples
> and gets the  result p<0.05, does this imply that the probability that
> a difference in the sample  means occurs by chance, while there is no
> difference in the population, is less than 5%?

I have no experience with what this means or if it's true or false. I only know that if P<0.05, I have to reject the null hypothesis, so the means are not equal. (I am a beginner in statistics)

Comment: Could you please cite where did this quote comes from?

Comment: @msuzen from an exercise for my class in statistics

Comment: Hint: when there is no difference in the population, why would you even need samples to compute this probability?